# Why does this SQL function have a side effect?

Tags: sql

In the book *[Database System Concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Silberschatz#Books)*:

> ```
> –– Registers_a student after ensuring classroom capacity is_not exceeded
> –– Returns_0 on success, and -1 if capacity is_exceeded.
> create function registerStudent(
>   in s_id varchar(5),
>   in s_courseid varchar (8),
>   in s_secid varchar (8),
>   in s_semester varchar (6),
>   in s_year numeric (4,0),
>   out errorMsg varchar(100)
> returns_integer
> begin
>   declare currEnrol int;
>   select count(*) into currEnrol
>     from takes
>     where course id = s_courseid and sec id = s_secid
>     and semester = s_semester and year = s_year;
>   declare limit int;
>   select capacity into limit
>     from classroom natural join section
>     where course id = s_courseid and sec id = s_secid
>     and semester = s_semester and year = s_year;
>   if (currEnrol < limit)
>   begin
>     insert into takes values
>       (s_id, s_courseid, s_secid, s_semester, s_year, null);
>     return(0);
>   end
>   –– Otherwise, section capacity limit already reached
>   set errorMsg = ’Enrollment limit reached for course ’ || s_courseid
>     || ’ section ’ || s_secid;
>   return(-1);
> end;
> ```
>
> **Figure 5.7 Procedure to register a student for a course section.**

The book has both function and procedure concepts. Isn't it that a function call cannot have side effect, while a procedure call can?

Does a call to the function in the above example have a side effect to

- `insert into takes values`,
- `set errorMsg = ’Enrollment limit reached for course ’ || s_courseid   || ’ section ’ || s_secid`,
- `select count(*) into currEnrol`?

Why can the function have a side effect?

In a SQL standard, such as SQL:1999 (mentioned in the quote) or SQL:2016, what are the answers to the above questions?

Comment: The book could be wrong. Modifying tables values/schema inside of a function was never intended to be supported and is not directly supported. System functions MAX/MIN/AVG/SUM will never modify data and following that standard, user defined functions are not meant to make permanent modifications either.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it is doing an INSERT then that is a side effect.

Comment: Thanks. In a SQL standard, such as SQL:1999 or SQL:2016, (1) does a function call have no side effect? (2) Does the set statement `set errorMsg = ’Enrollment limit reached for course ’ || s_courseid   || ’ section ’ || s_secid;` have side effect? (3) Does `select count(*) into currEnrol` have side effect?